# Splitting field.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

Show that   $\mathbb {Q }(\pi)$ is not splitting field over $\mathbb {Q }(\pi^2)$.

I am thinking $\mathbb {Q }(\pi)$  and $\mathbb {Q }(\pi^2)$ are same field 
Or $\mathbb {Q }(\pi)$ is not even a field so can not be splitting field?
Please give me some hint.

Comment: $\pi\notin \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$.

Comment: What is the splitting field of the polynomial $X^2 - \pi^2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$?

Comment: @David It is $\mathbb {Q }(\pi )$. So how to proceed further from here?

Comment: Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: @David I want to show it isn't.